Shortcode to return data instead of outputting HTML?
I’ve got a shortcode plugin which allows me to output a block of HTML in one of a few different formats based on parameters.
[mm-postlinking]
[mm-postlinking id="281493" template="thumbnail"]
[mm-postlinking template="link" link_text="View page"]
etc.

Currently all of the formats are visual, but I’m wondering if I can return a data object or associative array from the plugin instead of markup. Basically I have an area of my site that could use the data being generated by this plugin, but has it’s own layout. So it would be great if I could call the plugin (or code within the plugin), directly and get just the data back.
If it matters, the plugin code is class based. I'm on WordPress 6.4.4 and I'm explicitly not using Gutenberg (if that matters).

shortcodes are a system of embedding HTML generated at runtime by PHP in post content, they were never intended to be misused this way though that hasn't stopped people doing lots of unusual things with them. Given this, there's no built in mechanism for returning something that isn't a string. It would be easier to have a single shortcode and make direct PHP function calls inside it. Note that what you want to do might be possible with blocks though, blocks can pass data up and down via context, and it doesn't have to be a string
